# How to get a list of posts and check if the user already "Liked" them? (Check existing relation between two models)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having fun with Laravel framework trying to build a little "blog" site that works the following way:

- When you enter the webpage, a cached index of the latest / most popular posts is shown

There is a ManyToMany Relationship "user_likes" between the User and Post models, so that if you're logged in then you can "Like" or "upvote" each of these posts with a "heart" button, so that a relation between the two models will be created in the user_likes pivot table.

I have two database tables

users table:

```
user_id     name
   1        TheUser
```

posts table:

```
post_id     title
   1        MyPost
   2        Another Post
   3        Yet another post
```

user_likes pivot table:

```
post_id    user_id
  1           1
  3           1
```

And the User Model Class:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
protected $table = 'users';

    public function likes()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'user_likes','user_id','post_id');
    }

}
```

- The question is, what's an efficient way of retrieving a list of Post models and checking if the logged in User has already liked / upvoted them?

The thing is that i'd like to check for every Post if the relation between the logged in User and the Post model exists in the most efficient way.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This SQL Fiddle would be a way of achieving what I'd like to do, the problem is that If i'm not wrong, I won't be able to cache the posts, as I'll need to check them every time a new user logs in.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5bab/2

Using Laravel's Query builder:

```
DB::table('posts')
->leftJoin('user_likes', function($join) {
    $join->on('user_likes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
        ->where('user_likes.user_id', '=', 1);
})

->select('posts.id as post_id', 'posts.title', 'user_likes as did_i_like')
->groupBy('posts.id')
->orderBy('posts.id');
```

Right now, I'm doing it in my application in a different way:

I have the paginated posts cached, and then each User has a cached collection of the posts ids that they liked, so when they log in, I'll check if each post is in the user's liked post collection:

```
$liked = Auth::user()->getLikedPosts(); // returns a cached collection of the User liked posts ids
$posts = Post::popular(1); // returns a cached and paginated index of the most popular posts.
```

Then, I'll check if the liked collection contains the post id:

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
 .......
 if($liked->contains($post->id)
 {
 // show red Heart
 }
 else
 {
  // show gray heart
 }
 .......
```

I think It's not a good way of doing it, since the $liked collection will be growing a lot... However, with the new Query, I really don't know how could I cache the posts, so that I don't have to query the Database each time a user logs in or navigates throught the posts pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `If the user has already liked`, which user ?

Comment: There are no such thing as "best way of...". There are a whole lot of different ways to perform a task, but it gets too subjective when talking about the best way. The important thing is that you keep best programming practices in mind. This question is also very broad. It's like asking. What is the best way of creating a program of tic-tac-toe. Can please narrow it down and maybe give som example(s) of what you've tried?

Comment: The thing is that I'd like to get the list of posts and at the same time know if the logged in User model already liked those posts in an efficient "mysql" way

Comment: Do you have a relationship method with `User` in `Post` model? What is that ?

Answer (score 1):

I am honestly not sure if it's good or not, but I did it like this:

Post Model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like');
}

public function likedByUser()
{
    return $this->likes()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

than in blades:

```
@if(isset($post->likedByUser[0]))
style="background-position: right;" data-value="liked"
@endif
```

I don't much about speed, but I'm paginating 9-12 each time, so It's not that bad, I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

> What's an efficient way of retrieving a list of Post models and
>   checking if the logged in User has already liked / upvoted them?

in your `Post` model declare a relationship:

```
public function likedByUser()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_likes', 'post_id', 'user_id')
           ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

Then retrieve posts which has been liked by the logged in user like this:

```
$posts = Post::has('likedByUser')->get();
```

**Update:**

```
$posts = Post::get();
$firstPost = $posts->first();
$firstPost->has('likedByUser');
```

Also you may loop and check:

```
$posts = Post::get();
foreach($posts as $post) {
    if($post->has('likedByUser')) {
        // liked it
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to get All existing posts, not just the ones that are liked by the Auth User, but I need to get them with an attribute that tells if the User already liked the post. I'd like to do it in just One or two querys, and not check it in a foreach loop that will check every post one by one, creating a query for each of the posts.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer @WereWolf, However, doing a foreach loop to check every post will execute a new query to the database, right? So that If I have 100 posts, It will make 100 querys, and If there are many logged in users it the number of querys will grow a lot? Thanks in advance

Comment: yes but you may also try `$posts = Post::with('likedByUser')->get(); if($post->first()->getRelation('likedByUser')->count())`;

Comment: Also `$posts = Post::with('likedByUser')->get(); if(count($posts->first()->likedByUser)) { // ... }`.